# moving canvas box(undesired diagonal movement)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I currently have a box drawn with canvas that can move: left, up, right and down using arrow keys **and** *WASD* keys.

The problem:
When I press `W`, and while holding it I press `A`, the box in question will move in up-right direction(diagonal). This is an undesired effect.
I would like this "box" to be not capable of moving in diagonals.

And please explain why this effect happens, I don't understand the logic behind it.

My code is here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/stexplorer
And here:

```js
$(function() {
  var n = 3;
  var xD = 0;
  var yD = 0;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    render(); 
  }

  var ss = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 75
  };

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(ss.x, ss.y, ss.width, ss.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function move() {
    x = ss.x + (xD * n);
    y = ss.y + (yD * n);
    ss.x = x;
    ss.y = y;
    render();
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    // left
 xD = e.which == 37 ? -1 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 65 ? -1 : xD;
    // up
 yD = e.which == 38 ? -1 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 87 ? -1 : yD;
    // right
 xD = e.which == 39 ? 1 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 68 ? 1 : xD;
    // down
 yD = e.which == 40 ? 1 : yD;
 yD = e.which == 83 ? 1 : yD;
    e.preventDefault();
 });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // left
 xD = e.which == 37 ? 0 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 65 ? 0 : xD;
    // up
 yD = e.which == 38 ? 0 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 87 ? 0 : yD;
    // right
 xD = e.which == 39 ? 0 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 68 ? 0 : xD;
    // down
 yD = e.which == 40 ? 0 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 83 ? 0 : yD;
 e.preventDefault();
 });

  resizeCanvas();
  render();
  setInterval(move, .01);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind this is that the keydown events fire independently of each other, so pressing multiple keys at a time will trigger your function multiple times, changing the x and y values at the same time. You can block this by creating a variable which tracks if any keys are already pressed. For example:

```
var currentButton = undefined;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
if(currentButton !== undefined){ 
    return; // there is already a button pressed, don't do logic
}
xD = e.which == 37 ? -1 : xD;
xD = e.which == 65 ? -1 : xD;
// up
yD = e.which == 38 ? -1 : yD;
yD = e.which == 87 ? -1 : yD;
// right
xD = e.which == 39 ? 1 : xD;
xD = e.which == 68 ? 1 : xD;
// down
yD = e.which == 40 ? 1 : yD;
yD = e.which == 83 ? 1 : yD;

currentButton = e.which; // store which key is currently pressed
e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
if(e.which === currentButton){
     currentButton = undefined; // the button has been released, set to undefined again
}
// left
xD = e.which == 37 ? 0 : xD;
xD = e.which == 65 ? 0 : xD;
// up
yD = e.which == 38 ? 0 : yD;
yD = e.which == 87 ? 0 : yD;
// right
xD = e.which == 39 ? 0 : xD;
xD = e.which == 68 ? 0 : xD;
// down
yD = e.which == 40 ? 0 : yD;
yD = e.which == 83 ? 0 : yD;
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I changed `currentButton` with `btn`, now it doesn't work <http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/stexplorer>

Comment: Did you change all the references to currentButton? (theres two in the keydown method and two in the keyup method)

Comment: I changed every single one of them, I sent you the link if you want inspection it, btw thanks

Comment: Looks like you missed the one doing the comparison    `if(e.which === currentButton){
     btn = undefined;`